# Design for executing a "pipeline" of user-defined actions based on input

Tags: java, reflection, architecture

**Scenario**
A web service receives a request in the form of XML from some other system, based on the contents of this request the web service should perform an arbitrary number of user-definable tasks (such as storing the contents of the XML to a database, extracting certain values, making a call to some other service etc). The behaviour of the requesting system cannot be changed (e.g. to call different actions for different things).

**Proposed Design**
My proposed design would be to have an interface something like...

```
interface PipelineTask {
    public void Run(String xml);
}
```

With implementations of this for each user action, for example...

```
public class LogToDatabaseTask implements PipelineTask {
    public void Run(String xml) {
        db.store(xml); // some call to database to store.
    }
}
```

Then a database table containing rules (maybe as XPath expressions), and the class to invoke should those rules be satisfied by the received document. I'd then use reflection - or perhaps a factory(?) - to invoke the correct implementation and run it.

**Question**
To me, it sounds like there should be some kind of existing pattern to implement something like this which I've missed and can't find online anywhere. Would this kind of approach make sense - or is there some better, perhaps more flexible way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned, a rule seems a good fit for this case. You can define a rule that takes facts related to the current state and provide the next action in the sequence. Below is a simple java rule method as example. You can also use a rules framework like drools. The response from the rule can be used with a factory or a strategy:

For example, consider the sequence of actions:

UPDATE_DB 
EXTRACT_VALUES 
INVOKE_XYZ_SERVICE 
END

For every web service request check the rule after every step and execute actions until you receive a rule response with next action END. The rulerequest also contains the contents of input document:

```
public RuleResponse execute(RuleRequest request) {

    //initialization and extraction code here
    if(request.previousAction.equals("EXTRACT_VALUES") && ....) {
        RuleResponse.nextAction = "INVOKE_XYZ_SERVICE".
    }

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that you tagged the question as `Java`, but actually you can reuse a lot of the MSDN logical model of the [Pipes & filters design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568100.aspx). The article is very good and I've used already in Java modules.

First you can also read this about [Pipeline_software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(software)) - it helped me a lot with ideas.